# Integration using Newton-Cotes method in python

Tags: python, algorithm

Im trying to write a function in python that will integrate a given function using the Newton-Cotes method, and its returning some extremely strange results, where it sometimes gives the correct answer and others not (mostly wrong with -ve bounds). This is my code, if anyone could point out any mistakes it would be greatly appreciated :)

```
def integrate(function, a, b):
    coeff = [7,32,12,32,7]
    result = 0
    for i in range(0,len(coeff)):
        x = a + (i*(b-a))/(len(coeff)-1)
        result += coeff[i]*eval(function)
        print eval(function)
    result = result*((b-a)/90.)
    return result
```

The newton cotes formula I've been following is from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Cotes_formulas).

Example:

```
print integrate("x**3-4*x+9", -7, 7)
```

Returns: `-38` when the actual answer is `126`

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a complete example that runs and gives the wrong result.

Comment: Having said that, to me the bit that looks suspect is the use of `eval(function)`, I'd expect function to be a function and for you to use it like `function(x)` instead.

Comment: From what I know eval evaluates a string with the variables (in this case being x) and parses in whatever that variable is currently stored as. Adding in an example as well.

Answer (score 3):

Mysterious math behaviour is usually the result of forgetting that in Python 2, the default behaviour of integer division is truncating.  Adding `print x, eval(function)` inside the loop:

```
>>> integrate("x**2+4", 0, 5)
0 4
1 5
2 8
3 13
5 29
50.166666666666664
```

but

```
>>> integrate("x**2+4", 0., 5.)
0.0 4.0
1.25 5.5625
2.5 10.25
3.75 18.0625
5.0 29.0
61.666666666666664
```

Note that the evaluation points are wrong in the first one.  And after adding `from __future__ import division`, or 
'a = 1.0*a; b = 1.0*b` to the start:

```
>>> integrate("x**2+4", 0, 5)
0.0 4.0
1.25 5.5625
2.5 10.25
3.75 18.0625
5.0 29.0
61.666666666666664
```

or for your example:

```
>>> integrate("x**3-4*x+9", -7, 7)
-7.0 -306.0
-3.5 -19.875
0.0 9.0
3.5 37.875
7.0 324.0
126.0
```

The `eval` is a bad design choice, but it's not the source of the bug.

Comment: I just found that I wasnt dividing by a float which was the cause of the answers sometimes being right. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that works, as @DSM points out, the problem is with the integer definition of limiting bounds of the integration.  It integrates a 'func()'.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

def integrate(function, a, b):
    coeff = [7,32,12,32,7]
    result = 0
    for i in range(0,len(coeff)):
        x = a + (i*(b-a))/(len(coeff)-1)
        result += coeff[i]*function(x)
        #print function(x)
    result = result*((b-a)/90.)
    return result

def func(x):
    return x**3-4*x+9

print integrate(func,-7.0,7.0)
```

On my computer it gives 126.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Try `integrate(func, -7, 7)`.

Comment: I gives: -38.2666666667
Ok, I'm now trying to digest your post :)